# Mysql php complex query

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to make a query, to find out if a player is in a match, and if his status isn't quit (6). The query below isn't working though. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM matches WHERE 
        (player1Name = '$name' AND player1Status != 6) || 
        (player2Name = '$name' AND player2Status != 6) || 
        (player3Name = '$name' AND player3Status != 6) ||
        (player4Name = '$name' AND player4Status != 6) ||
        (player5Name = '$name' AND player5Status != 6) ||
        (player6Name = '$name' AND player6Status != 6)
        ");
```

Comment: player1Status field is string or integer in database ?

Comment: just try to `echo $query` and check what it the result?

I have reached you problem. just tell me immediately.

Comment: What does "Not working" mean exactly? Are you getting errors, or are you not getting any results?

Comment: can u provide table structure with sample data?

Comment: player1Status is an integer (tinyint(2))

Comment: -1 This is poorly written question, update it, add detailed description of the problem, output of `echo mysql_error()` after query finishes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both OR and || are legit as it says [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/non-typed-operators.html).You could try PDO format as recommended [here](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/):

The DB connection is like this (with your db details, of course):

```
$dsn = "mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=reportslave1";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
try {
    $DBH = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

The prep work like this:

```
$STH = $DBH->prepare("SELECT * FROM matches WHERE 
      (player1Name = :name AND player1Status != 6) OR
      (player2Name = :name AND player2Status != 6) OR
      (player3Name = :name AND player3Status != 6) OR
      (player4Name = :name AND player4Status != 6) OR
      (player5Name = :name AND player5Status != 6) OR
      (player6Name = :name AND player6Status != 6) 
    ");

$STH->bindParam(":name",$name);
```

The call is then made as follows.

```
try {
  $STH->execute();
  $STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
catch(PDOException $e){
  echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: A pleasure, sir :) (Or ma'am - can't be sure!)

Answer (score 3):

In SQL, `||` is the concatenation operator (like `.` in PHP). Use `OR` instead.

Comment: It seems that's not entirely true for [mySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/logical-operators.html#operator_or) `||,OR` is apparently logical operator.

Comment: It can be configured: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_pipes_as_concat

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to change the structure of your schema. If you ever find yourself creating columns like player1Name,player1Status, player2Name, player2Status, player3Name, there's almost certainly something wrong with your schema.
You could try something like this

```
matches
-------
match_id (int)
...other match info columns

players
-------
player_id (int)
player_name (varchar)

matches_players
---------------
match_id
player_id
status
```

Your query could then easily become

```
SELECT *
FROM matches_players mp
    INNER JOIN players p ON mp.player_id=p.player_id
WHERE p.name='$name'
    AND mp.status != 6
```

Comment: I concur with the liquorvicar - there has to be a better way to organise the DB :)

Comment: sounds much better... I have about 60 rows in the "active_matches" structure... 8 rows for each players... I don't quite get how the above code works.. Is there any good documentation or tutorial where I can learn about how to create a good schema? THanks

Comment: @user1251004 Well, database design is a huge topic: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_design I'm not sure I can recommend anything as I've learnt by experience, by osmosis.

Comment: got it. I'll read up on some basics first and take it from there. Thanks

Comment: If it was me, I would follow the liquor vicar's example and assign a unique match id and player id to the match and player record. I wouldn't have a matches_players table, though. When a player joins a game, I'd update fields in the match and player records. So... Match has: id, p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6. Player has: id, status, m_num, p_num (match number and player number). If player #179 joins match 32 as the 3rd player, you find player id 179 and set status to 1, m_num to 32 and p_num to 3. You also find match 32, and set p3 to 179. When the player quits, you unset everything/set status to 6.

Comment: @Nick Er, that's the opposite of what I'm suggesting! As I said, if you ever find yourself creating columns like p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6 there is probably something wrong with your design.

Comment: So it was! I confess I'm not entirely convinced that another table providing the links is the most efficient way forward, although I suspect I'm underestimating the power of INNER JOIN :) And I'm not morally outraged by having six player ids in the match record, although having six statuses too is beyond the pale in my book. In conclusion, I defer to your wisdom (although if I'm honest, I'd probably do it my way in practice!)

Comment: @Nick http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalisation would be a good starting point for further reading. This isn't really "my" wisdom, it's fairly basic database design theory...

Comment: Yes, I could claim "selective denormalization ... for performance reasons" but I'd just be trying to cover my ignorance :)

Comment: For what it's worth, I'm now completely convinced. The liquorvicar's method is far superior :)

Answer (score 0):

Got it try below code:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM matches WHERE 
        (player1Name = '".$name."' AND player1Status != 6) OR 
        (player2Name = '".$name."' AND player2Status != 6) OR 
        (player3Name = '".$name."' AND player3Status != 6) OR
        (player4Name = '".$name."' AND player4Status != 6) OR
        (player5Name = '".$name."' AND player5Status != 6) OR
        (player6Name = '".$name."' AND player6Status != 6)
        ");
```

This will work.

Comment: I dont think so , it will make any difference.

Comment: That doesn't make any change...magic quotes should only be used in case of array variables like '".$row['variable']."' or '".$_SESSION['variable']."'

Comment: it makes sense guys. I think you don't know that $var will be print as same as it is within a single quote and that's why the php cann't recognise that is a variable or a string.

Comment: @GauravVashishtha That is only true if the string is enclosed in single quotes. The OP's query is enclosed in double quotes (inside which variables are evaluated), it merely contains single quotes. Example: http://codepad.org/8QsTfUPF